# How in WordPress open info on page step by step?

Tags: wordpress, navigation, pagespeed, deezer

I use WordPress and make [test page](http://isite.esy.es/music/) on which I want to add a `Deezer Musik` albums (many different albums) on this page. But when there will be many (for example 50-100 alboms) page will be loaded for a long time.

How to make so you can open page and page show not all (50-100) alboms same times? Page show first, for example, 5 or 10 albums and then you pushed button (or scrolling) and page show next 5 to 10 albums, and next... Not all at the same time. Step by step.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand exactly what you want to do. I saw that you load 8 Deezer widgets, do you need all of them? What do you want to do with it? If you want to control them, you can use our Javascript SDK, like here: http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/example-basic

Comment: I want to add albums to this page from the site deezer (want to add a lot). But when on the page will be a lot of albums (for example 100 - 200 albums) page will be a long time to load. Is it possible when the page opens to display, for example, 5 albums, then click on the button on this page has 5 albums, so the page is loaded, not all at once but step by step?

Comment: No, sorry but it is not possible to do that way. You can group them in some playlists if you want, it can be another way.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'm not good in the code. My level of programming is very low. I'll find another way. But I have to turn on the music on the site. Because it is the soul of the site:) and only deezer. Deezer is a very neat site. Do not want to playlist, I want to keep the style of the album (in deezer it well done). I will put the album in the footer on the home page. Only need to change it periodically. Like this http://isite.esy.es/